# How do I fix "no-unused-vars" for main entry Browserify js file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, eslint

I use Gulp and Browserify to be able to use ES6 imports, as well as ESLint to apply coding standards.

So I need one entry file for Browserify which only imports all my other files:

```
import Carousel from "./bootstrap/carousel";
import Transition from "./bootstrap/transition";
import Header from "./header/header";
```

Unfortunately, ESLint complains

```
data/themes/js/src/main.js
  1:8  error  'Carousel' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
  2:8  error  'Transition' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  3:8  error  'Header' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
```

I wouldn't like to disable the rule (although I could do it only for that file)

Comment: you need to export them or diable the rule in eslint

Comment: Use `import "..."` instead? But the setup is strange. Do these files do anything on their own? If not, how do you access what they define/export?

Comment: What do you mean export them?

Comment: @FelixKling : they add some DOM event listeners etc.. the other two are Bootstrap plugins. I'm open to all suggestions as the architecture in general is important for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import a module purely for its side-effects, you can use

```
import "module";
```

Comment: I guess that should do it. `import "./header/header.js"` . Thanks. Bonus question: Setup-wise : should I just do a multi-entry setup for Browserify in order to drop the actual "main.js" file that just imports the rest? any tips?

Comment: No tips, I haven't used browserify in a while, sorry.

Comment: Browserify aside, would importing modules purely for side-effects be a good idea architecturally?

Comment: Well, it's not *great*, but in the end, the "root module/file" is also only loaded for its side effects. So as long as it is close to the top, I wouldn't worry about it too much.